# Dom-to-image printing only first chart ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, dom, ionic4, jspdf

I have an Ionic page (page 2) that receives an id number, start date and end date from the previous page (page 1), sends a JSON to the API and receives two arrays: one for dates and one for measurements. Then, the arrays are put in a graph and shown.

When the user clicks the button “print to pdf”, the library dom-to-image transforms the canvas in which the graph is placed into a png image and puts it in a generated PDF file which is finally stored in the users device.

If the user presses the button “print to pdf” once, the process works fine.

If the user presses the button “print to pdf” once, receives the pdf, comes back to page 1, inputs other dates to recalculate the graph and presses another time the button “print to pdf”, the the graph shown in the pdf is the previous, not the newly generated. However, the graph shown in the screen is the newly generated…

Here the code for the graph population:

(loadQuarantineStatsDefault()) is loaded in ionViewWillEnter()

```
loadQuarantineStatsDefault(){
return new Promise(resolve => {
    let body = {
    serial_numb : this.serial_number,
    fecha_inicio : this.fecha_inicio,
    fecha_final : this.fecha_final
  };
             
  this.postPvdr.postData(body, 'proses_tower.php').subscribe(array_data => {
    this.array_data = array_data['array_data'];
    resolve(true);

    for(var i:number=0; i<this.array_data.length; i++){
      this.array_dates[i] = this.array_data[i]['fecha_hora'];
      this.array_co2[i] = this.array_data[i]['co2'];
      this.array_tvoc[i] = this.array_data[i]['tvoc'];
      this.array_temperature[i] = this.array_data[i]['temperature'];
      this.array_humidity[i] = this.array_data[i]['humidity'];
    }
    
    this.array_dates.reverse();
    this.array_co2.reverse();
    this.array_tvoc.reverse();
    this.array_temperature.reverse();
    this.array_humidity.reverse();

    if(this.data_selector=="co2"){
      this.array_selected_data = this.array_co2;
      this.array_label = 'Medición de CO₂ (ppm)';
      this.backgroundColor1 = 'white';
      this.yAxisSegement1 = 0;
      this.backgroundColor2 = 'white'; 
      this.yAxisSegement2 = 0;
      this.backgroundColor3 = 'white'; 
      this.yAxisSegement3 = 0;
      this.backgroundColor4 = 'white'; 
      this.yAxisSegement4 = 0;
      this.backgroundColor5 = 'rgb(0, 184, 175, 0.4)'; 
      this.yAxisSegement5 = 600;
      this.backgroundColor6 = 'rgb(255, 235, 59, 0.4)'; 
      this.yAxisSegement6 = 1000;
      this.backgroundColor7 = 'rgb(255, 152, 0, 0.4)'; 
      this.yAxisSegement7 = 1500;
      this.backgroundColor8 = 'rgb(255, 87, 34, 0.4)'; 
      this.yAxisSegement8 = 2500;
      this.backgroundColor9 = 'rgb(229, 57, 53, 0.4)'; 
      this.yAxisSegement9 = Infinity;
    }

    if(this.data_selector=="tvoc"){
      this.array_selected_data = this.array_tvoc;
      this.array_label = 'Medición de TVOC (ppb)';
      this.backgroundColor1 = 'white';
      this.yAxisSegement1 = 0;
      this.backgroundColor2 = 'white'; 
      this.yAxisSegement2 = 0;
      this.backgroundColor3 = 'white'; 
      this.yAxisSegement3 = 0;
      this.backgroundColor4 = 'white'; 
      this.yAxisSegement4 = 0;
      this.backgroundColor5 = 'rgb(0, 184, 175, 0.4)'; 
      this.yAxisSegement5 = 333;
      this.backgroundColor6 = 'rgb(255, 235, 59, 0.4)'; 
      this.yAxisSegement6 = 1000;
      this.backgroundColor7 = 'rgb(255, 152, 0, 0.4)'; 
      this.yAxisSegement7 = 3333;
      this.backgroundColor8 = 'rgb(255, 87, 34, 0.4)'; 
      this.yAxisSegement8 = 8332;
      this.backgroundColor9 = 'rgb(229, 57, 53, 0.4)'; 
      this.yAxisSegement9 = Infinity;
    }

    if(this.data_selector=="temperatura"){
      this.array_selected_data = this.array_temperature;
      this.array_label = 'Medición de Temperatura (ºC)';
      this.backgroundColor1 = 'rgb(229, 57, 53, 0.4)';
      this.yAxisSegement1 = 9;
      this.backgroundColor2 = 'rgb(255, 87, 34, 0.4)'; 
      this.yAxisSegement2 = 11;
      this.backgroundColor3 = 'rgb(255, 152, 0, 0.4)'; 
      this.yAxisSegement3 = 17;
      this.backgroundColor4 = 'rgb(255, 152, 0, 0.4)'; 
      this.yAxisSegement4 = 18;
      this.backgroundColor5 = 'rgb(0, 184, 175, 0.4)'; 
      this.yAxisSegement5 = 25;
      this.backgroundColor6 = 'rgb(255, 152, 0, 0.4)'; 
      this.yAxisSegement6 = 26;
      this.backgroundColor7 = 'rgb(255, 152, 0, 0.4)'; 
      this.yAxisSegement7 = 31;
      this.backgroundColor8 = 'rgb(255, 87, 34, 0.4)'; 
      this.yAxisSegement8 = 33;
      this.backgroundColor9 = 'rgb(229, 57, 53, 0.4)'; 
      this.yAxisSegement9 = Infinity;
    }

    if(this.data_selector=="humedad"){
      this.array_selected_data = this.array_humidity;
      this.array_label = 'Medición de Humedad (%)';
      this.backgroundColor1 = 'rgb(229, 57, 53, 0.4)';
      this.yAxisSegement1 = 15;
      this.backgroundColor2 = 'rgb(255, 87, 34, 0.4)'; 
      this.yAxisSegement2 = 20;
      this.backgroundColor3 = 'rgb(255, 152, 0, 0.4)'; 
      this.yAxisSegement3 = 35;
      this.backgroundColor4 = 'rgb(255, 235, 59, 0.4)'; 
      this.yAxisSegement4 = 40;
      this.backgroundColor5 = 'rgb(0, 184, 175, 0.4)'; 
      this.yAxisSegement5 = 50;
      this.backgroundColor6 = 'rgb(255, 235, 59, 0.4)'; 
      this.yAxisSegement6 = 60;
      this.backgroundColor7 = 'rgb(255, 152, 0, 0.4)'; 
      this.yAxisSegement7 = 65;
      this.backgroundColor8 = 'rgb(255, 87, 34, 0.4)'; 
      this.yAxisSegement8 = 80;
      this.backgroundColor9 = 'rgb(229, 57, 53, 0.4)'; 
      this.yAxisSegement9 = Infinity;      
    }

    if(this.serial_numb_confirm==undefined || this.tower_name == undefined){
      this.loadQuarantineStatsDefault(this.username);
    }

    if (this.bars) this.bars.destroy();

    this.bars = new Chart(this.barChart.nativeElement, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: this.array_dates,
        datasets: [{
          label: this.array_label,
          data: this.array_selected_data,
          backgroundColor: 'rgb(27, 18, 64, 0.0)', 
          borderColor: '#00b8af',
          borderWidth: 3,
          pointBackgroundColor:'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)',
          pointBorderWidth: 1,
          pointHitRadius: 8,
          pointHoverBorderWidth: 1,
          pointHoverRadius: 4,
          pointRadius: 3,
        }]
      },
      options: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'TOWER "' + this.tower_name + '" (' + this.serial_numb_confirm + ')'
        },  
        backgroundRules: [{
          backgroundColor: this.backgroundColor1, 
          yAxisSegement: this.yAxisSegement1
      }, {
          backgroundColor: this.backgroundColor2, 
          yAxisSegement: this.yAxisSegement2
      }, {
          backgroundColor: this.backgroundColor3, 
          yAxisSegement: this.yAxisSegement3
      }, {
          backgroundColor: this.backgroundColor4, 
          yAxisSegement: this.yAxisSegement4
      }, {
          backgroundColor: this.backgroundColor5, 
          yAxisSegement: this.yAxisSegement5
      }, {
          backgroundColor: this.backgroundColor6, 
          yAxisSegement: this.yAxisSegement6
      }, {
          backgroundColor: this.backgroundColor7, 
          yAxisSegement: this.yAxisSegement7
      }, {
          backgroundColor: this.backgroundColor8, 
          yAxisSegement: this.yAxisSegement8
      }, {
          backgroundColor: this.backgroundColor9, 
          yAxisSegement: this.yAxisSegement9
      }],
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true,
            }
          }],
          xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true,
              autoSkip: true,
              maxRotation: 90,
              minRotation: 90,
              maxTicksLimit: 24
            }
          }]
        }
      },
      plugins: [{
        beforeDraw: function (chart) {
            var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
            var ruleIndex = 0;
            var rules = chart.chart.options.backgroundRules;
            var yaxis = chart.chart.scales["y-axis-0"];
            var xaxis = chart.chart.scales["x-axis-0"];
            var partPercentage = 1 / (yaxis.ticksAsNumbers.length - 1);
            for (var i = yaxis.ticksAsNumbers.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                if (yaxis.ticksAsNumbers[i] < rules[ruleIndex].yAxisSegement) {
                    ctx.fillStyle = rules[ruleIndex].backgroundColor;
                    ctx.fillRect(xaxis.left, yaxis.top + ((i - 1) * (yaxis.height * partPercentage)), xaxis.width, yaxis.height * partPercentage);
                } else {
                    ruleIndex++;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }]

    });   

  });
        
});
```

}

Here the code for the graph saving into pdf:

```
public saveGraph() {
var div = document.getElementById("barChart");
console.log('div', div);
var options = { background: "white", quality: 0.99, height: 800, width: 800, cacheBust: true};
domtoimage.toPng(div, options).then((dataUrl)=> {
  //Initialize JSPDF
  var doc = new jspdf("p","mm","a4");
  //Add image Url to PDF
  var graph = new Image();
  graph.src = dataUrl;
  doc.addImage(graph, 'PNG', 20, 40, 170, 128);
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = 'https://xx.com/xx/logos/color_compressed.png';
  doc.addImage(img, "PNG", 163, 5, 40, 23); 


  let pdfOutput = doc.output();
  // using ArrayBuffer will allow you to put image inside PDF
  let buffer = new ArrayBuffer(pdfOutput.length);
  let array = new Uint8Array(buffer);
  for (var i = 0; i < pdfOutput.length; i++) {
      array[i] = pdfOutput.charCodeAt(i);
  }


  //This is where the PDF file will stored , you can change it as you like
  // for more information please visit https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/
  const directory = this.file.dataDirectory ;
  const fileName = "Exportación_gráfico_mediciones.pdf" + new Date().getTime();
  let options: IWriteOptions = { replace: true };

    //Writing File to Device
    this.file.writeFile(directory,fileName,buffer, options)
    .then((success)=> {
      console.log("File created Succesfully" + JSON.stringify(success));
      this.fileOpener.open(this.file.dataDirectory + fileName, 'application/pdf')
    })
    .catch((error)=> {
      console.log("Cannot Create File " +JSON.stringify(error));
    });
    //Writing File to Device
    this.file.writeFile(directory,fileName,buffer)
    .then((success)=> {
      console.log("File created Succesfully" + JSON.stringify(success));
      this.fileOpener.open(this.file.dataDirectory + fileName, 'application/pdf')
        .then(() => console.log('File is opened'))
        .catch(e => console.log('Error opening file', e));
    })
    .catch((error)=> {
      console.log("Cannot Create File " +JSON.stringify(error));
    });
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
});
```

}

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div id="graphcontainer" style="height: 68%">
  <canvas width=643 height=484 id="barChart" #barChart></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: It's a little bit complicated sample. Can you build the test project (with sample data) with your problem?

Comment: I'm sorry @DanilProkhorenko I don't really understand the question. I can build the project and run it in my device with no errors.

Comment: I mean can you create a sample project (and upload it on GitHub) where your problem can be reproduced?

Comment: @DanilProkhorenko so sorry for late response. Unfortunatelly, it is impossible to upload the full project to GitHub as it is private and I do not have te permission to do it... However, as a hint, I am experiencing that, after adding the following line of code `ionViewWillLeave(){ this.bars.destroy(); }`, the first pdf is shown with the correct graph and the second without any graph. Maybe that tells you something..

Comment: Continuing with above message, if I print again the pdf (3rd time) with the 1st graph, it is printed correctly... Might be something about the DOM?

Comment: Do you use the same DOM element to draw a chart? And which lib do you use to draw a chart?

Comment: Yes, I do use the same DOM element to draw the chart. I uploaded the html code. I use chartjs library

Comment: Hm... I tried to reproduce your problem but nothing. At this moment I have one idea. Try to call `resolve(true)` after creating `Chart` in your `loadQuarantineStatsDefault` function but not right away after getting data.